# How do we handle navigation between pages in a Page object Model test framework

Tags: ruby, navigation, cucumber, bdd, pageobjects

I'm using a BDD Cucumber framework with ruby to test a website. And I'm following the Page Object Model pattern. I have a different class for each page with its elements and functions and a separate feature file for each which has scenarios related to that page.

I'm quite new to POM structure and got a doubt:

Now, if I want to have a scenario which involves starting from Home Page, navigating through menus/submenus and ending up on a certain Page1 of the site and I wanna verify I'm on the right page either through the url or title.

1. Should I place such a scenario in home_page.feature or page_1.feature?
2. If I start with Home Page, obviously my @page variable will be loaded with Home Page , so when and where should I change it Page1, as I will need Page1 elements to verify the last step(a url, title or image etc, that I'm on Page1)
3. How do people generally structure their tests around navigation with POM framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate through a page by the page name and value, different values can mean different pages.

```
# Given I am on page users board
Given /^I am on page ?(.+)?$/ do |page_name|
  case page_name
  when 'homepage'
    visit root_path
  when 'users board'
    visit users_path
  when 'products board'
    visit product_path
  else
    raise "Missing mapping for '#{page_name}' page."
  end
end
```

It will raise `Missing mapping for '#{page_name}' page.` exception if the page name is not defined.

Find out other ways to use cucumber tests in this [article](https://kolosek.com/cucumber-cheat-sheet/).

Answer (score 0):

We created navigation feature file that have `<MENU>` and Sub Menu Link to answer your first question.

//To verify All links are present

```
   Feature : verify all submenu links 
    Given as user I logs in "http://stackoverflow.com/ 
    When I click on menu "<StackExchange>" 
    Then I able to see following submenu link"<Meta Stack Overflow,Stack overFlow Careers>"
```

Here is structure Idea that we have right now for navigation

- We have one class for each page and we have separate class for header, footer, right side menu
- All menu have expected behavior if I click on home page than I will on be on Home page. Each menu return expected object and using that object we verified Title and expected elements. Here when I click on home page link and it will return HomePagePOM.class and Using this object I can verify page
- In Navigation class it will have all menu and sub menu and return expected object.